# Why does my audio play before the Sprite Kit scene transition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

In this code, `Audio` is a class where all things concerning `AVAudioPlayer` are handled. Currently there is some music playing. I want to have this fade out completely in 1 second and then play another song. Simultaneously, I want a new scene to appear. So I want the new song to start right as the transition (also lasting 1 second) ends. However, I find myself always waiting for the music to stop, before the scene transition starts. I've tried many ways, with and without selectors, with and without the various sleep functions, but without any luck. I've also tried to use `stopMusic` instead of `transitionMusic` and then use `playMusic:` in the new scene, but I always find myself waiting for `stopMusic` to finish before the transition starts.

Here's a part of the first scene, which is run if a certain button on the screen is pressed:

```
Audio *musicPlayer = [[Audio alloc] init];
NewScene *newScene = [NewScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:1.0];
reveal.pausesOutgoingScene = NO;
reveal.pausesIncomingScene = NO;
[self.view presentScene:newScene transition:reveal];
[musicPlayer transitionMusic:@"NewSong"];
```

The method `transitionMusic:` is as follows:

```
-(void)transitionMusic:(NSString *)fileName {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopMusic) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self playMusic:fileName];
}
```

And `stopMusic` and `playMusic:` are:

```
-(void)stopMusic {
    while(BGM.volume > 0.05) {     
        [BGM setVolume:(BGM.volume - 0.05)];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];   
    }
    [BGM stop];    
}

-(void)playMusic:(NSString *)fileName {    
    NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName] withExtension:@"caf"];
    BGM = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:nil];
    [BGM setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [BGM setVolume:1.0];
    [BGM prepareToPlay];
    [BGM play];   
}
```

Also, `BGM` is a static audioplayer declared in `Audio.h`. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to do a simpler transition and in didMoveToView do a fade in and start music together in runAction call.

Comment: @uchuugaka: I edited my post since your comment. I had already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Your musicPlayer player object is dependent on your old scene. You need to create a singleton to handle your transition music independently from one scene to another.

BoxesOfBabies.com has a good tutorial on how to set up a singleton and use it to [Control Music Across Multiple SKScene](http://www.boxesofbabies.com/tutorial/detail/7/Control-Music-Across-Multiple-SKScene).

EDIT:

In your SKScene:

```
#import "MySingleton"

@implementation MainScene
{
    MySingleton *_mySingleton;
}
```

In your init method:

```
_mySingleton = [MySingleton sharedInstance];
```

To start playing audio in any of your scenes:

```
[_mySingleton startPlayingSong1];
```

or

```
[_mySingleton startPlayingSong2];
```

whatever methods you have in your singleton.

Comment: Does it have to be a subclass of `NSObject`? Right now I have the `Audio` class, but it is a subclass of `AVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: @Deeyennay - NSObject is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies. You can have a singleton from practically any class. I am currently using a SKSpriteNode singleton.

Comment: I have implemented it, but I still have to wait for the music to fade out completely and the new music to start, before the transition starts. I've tried using `stopMusic` in the old scene and `playMusic:` in the new scene, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Deeyennay - Are you familiar with singletons?

Comment: Not that much. I thought it was just a way to have your class create only one object and then share that object with other classes. Can those two processes (fade music out and transition to other scene) even run simultaneously?

Comment: @Deeyennay - I added some code examples for singletons.

Comment: I've done that. Still have to wait for the fade before the transition starts. Any idea what else it could be?